# Small signal output impedance for a circuit with bipolar transistor?

Tags: transistors, bjt, impedance, small-signal

For the following circuit, I need to find the **small-signal impedance looking into the collector of the transistor at terminal X,** not taking the load resistance Z into account:

[image]

My attempt at a SSM is:
[image]

Now, as I understand it, the small signal impedance looking into the collector is just another way of saying output impedance **(please do correct me if I am wrong)**. So we essentially need to find the small signal output impedance from the SSM.

To do so, we need to short the input, and apply a test voltage at the output. However, I can't see just by inspection what the input and the output even are on this SSM. **Is \$v_{be}\$ or \$v_b\$ the input? Is \$v_{ce}\$ or \$v_c\$ the output?**

My intuitive guess would be the input is between the base and small signal ground, \$v_b\$, and the output is between the collector and small signal ground \$v_c\$. But I have no real logic to justify this.

And if that were the case, if we shorted the input, we would be connecting the base to ground. And hence, **the parallel combination of R1 and R2 should disappear in the calculation of output impedance**.

But, as it turns out, the expression for the small signal output impedance is:
[image]

And it *does* include the parallel combination of R1 and R2 (denoted \$R_{12}\$ here).

So, I'm sort of at a loss here, and clarification on (1) firstly identifying the inputs and outputs of the circuit and (2) why \$R_{12}\$ appears in the expression for small signal output impedance, would be much appreciated.

Comment: If we want to find Rout we are looking from the load resistance perspective. In this case, we see two paths for the AC current to flow. The first path is through Z resistance and the 
And the second one through BJT's From colletor into BJT collector. So, to find resistance seen from the collector terminal into the BJT we need to use a small signal model.

Comment: So in this case the input (for our test voltage ) is at the collector.  Look here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/613568/output-resistance-bjt-regarding-early-effect#comment1618479_613568

Comment: @G36 Regarding your first comment, I have used a small signal model (or at least attempted to).

Comment: As for the second question, it looks like Vin source is connected via R1. And this is why R1||R2 are included in SSM. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/265046/calculation-of-output-impedance-of-ce-emitter-bias-configuration-unbypassed-wi/276764#276764

Comment: Today I found time to check your equation for Rout. It looks like a mess but despite this it is correct. Personally prefer this version $$ r_{out} = \frac{1}{h_{oe}} \left(1 + \frac{R_E}{R_E+(h_{ie} + R_{12})}\beta\right)+R_E||(h_{ie} + R_{12})$$

Comment: Could you please show me your working and also the SSM you used? Maybe in an answer to the question?

Comment: But I already did that. Haven't you seen this https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/265046/calculation-of-output-impedance-of-ce-emitter-bias-configuration-unbypassed-wi/276764#276764 or this https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/613568/output-resistance-bjt-regarding-early-effect#comment1618479_613568  Do you have any questions about it?